# how to extract the multiple folders inside jar

Tags: unix

i have multiple folders. each folders having lot of jars. i want to extract all the jars in root directory with single command. please advice

Comment: your question title and description do not match.

Comment: with a command i want to extract all the jars inside of multiple folders. please anyone advice to me.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by command:

```
 cp $(find /rootfolder/with/jars -name "*.jar") /folder/for/jars
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find path -type f -name *.jar -exec unzip {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is still a little unclear, but as I understand it, you want to find all the jars in multiple folders, and then extract them in place.  That can be done in UNIX with

```
$ find /top/directory -name '*.jar' -exec jar xf {} \;
```

Comment: i don’t want to find the jars in multiple folders, i want to extract the jars where ever it is available in parent folder. eg: suresh/folder1/folder2/a.jar, suresh/foldera/folderb/b.jar i want to extract all the jars in respective folders using one command, that command I should run in parent folder(suresh). If i run the command, the a.jar & b.jar should extract.

Comment: You're pretty new at this aren't you?  Suresh, the command above does exactly that.  Read man find and man jar.